# Homotopy type of mapping space

Tags: algebraic-topology

In Ralph Cohen's notes on the topology of fiber bundles (pp.63) he claims that the space of all $G$-equivariant maps from $P$ to $EG$ denoted by Map$^G(P,EG)$ is aspherical, where $EG$ is the total space of the classifying space $BG$ and $P$ is any principal $G$-bundle.  Could somebody help me to see why it is true? Is it because $EG$ is aspherical by the definition of universal bundle?

Comment: There is an answer here [link](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/130078/the-classifying-space-of-a-gauge-group), in fact it shows that it is contractible.

Comment: Well, the mapping space has a free action of the gauge group and the point of showing that it is contractible is to identify that the quotient is a classifying space for the gauge group. So being fair, it really has an appropriate title.